# Is there a general closed-form formula of the derivates of a feedforward network?

Tags: neural-networks, derivative, gradient

I am looking for a general closed-form formula for the derivatives of a Feed-forward Network with respect **to the inputs**.

Mathematically, we can write:

$$
\mathbf{y} = f_{FF}(\mathbf{x}) =
\mathbf{W}_{h} 
(\sigma_{h-1}(\mathbf{W}_{h-1} (\ldots  \sigma_0(\mathbf{W}_0 \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}_0) \ldots) + \mathbf{b}_{h-1}))
+ \mathbf{b}_{h}
$$

Assuming all the activation functions being identical and equal to the $\tanh$, that is $\sigma_h(\cdot) = \tanh(\cdot)$, is there a general closed-formula for the $k$-th order derivatives of $\mathbf{y} = [y_0, \ldots, y_j]$ with respect to $\mathbf{x} = [x_0, \ldots, x_i]$?:

$$
\frac{\partial^k \mathbf{y}^i}{\partial {x^i}^k} = ?
$$

This question is a generalization of [Neural network derivative with respect to input](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/505116/223596)